# Question about completion of DVR.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $(R, (\pi))$ be a discrete valuation ring with residue class field $R/(\pi) \cong k$. It is well known that if $k$ embedds into $R$, then there is an isomorphism of the completion $\hat{R} \cong k [[ T ]]$.

Assume $A$ is a $k$-algebra. How can I show that the (according) completion $\widehat{A \otimes_k R}$ (along the ideal $(1 \otimes \pi)$) is isomorphic to $A[[T]]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [this result](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102557/completion-and-tensor-product-of-algebras) with $A=R$ and $B=R\otimes_kA$ and $\widehat{k[[T]]\otimes_kA}\simeq A[[T]]$.

Comment: Well, this was not only a hint but more like a full solution. Thank you! This was a bit more than just a hint. However: do you know a reference in literature for the statement of the mathoverflow link or mine? Otherwise the proof could become a bit lengthy and more prominent than I would wish for.

Comment: Yes, I first thought it would be some lines longer. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking again and it might sound stupid, but are you sure that $k[[T]] \otimes_k A \cong A[[T]]$?

Comment: Dear @Louis, This is not always true. If $k=\mathbf{Q}$ and $A=\mathbf{C}$, $\mathbf{C}[[T]]$ is way bigger than $\mathbf{Q}[[T]]\otimes_\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{C}$. The latter has power series that are $\mathbf{C}$-linear combinations of power series over $\mathbf{Q}$, and not all elements of $\mathbf{C}[[T]]$ look like this. It's true if $k\to A$ is finite, but not generally otherwise.

Comment: @Louis It was a typo. I've forgot a hat.

Comment: @user: I see. Is the isomorphism stated now easy to show/see? I've employed theorem 7.16 from Eisenbud now to show the statement, but maybe your argument is more elegant.

Comment: @Louis Do you mean to the last isomorphism?

Comment: Yes, the $\widehat{k[[t]] \otimes_k A} \cong A[[T]]$. But I guess it's just clear because $k[[T]]/(T^n) \cong k[T]/(T^n)$?